# Java Generics Of Generics

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface:

```
public interface Human<D extends Details> {
    D getDetails();
}
```

And a concrete impl:

```
public class Man implements Human<ManDetails> {
    ManDetails getDetails();
}
```

I'd like to extend Man in such a way so I could do something like:

```
public class Baby extends Man {
    BabyDetails getDetails();
}
```

So basically I'm looking for a way so Man would be concrete (I would be able to use it on it's own) but also a generic so others can extends it (for example, getDetails() of baby will get super.getDetails() and create a new instance of BabyDetails from it).

Comment: Is `BabyDetails`  a subclass of `ManDetails`?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for not mentioning, Details is also an inteface and ManDetails impl it.

Comment: In general, you should aim to avoid concrete classes extending other concrete classes.

Comment: Then what you have should already be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider changing your code to

```
class Man<T extends ManDetails> implements Human<T> {
    public T getDetails(){return null;}
}
```

which would let you do something like

```
class Baby extends Man<BabyDetails> {
    public BabyDetails getDetails(){...}
}
```

or

```
class Baby<T extends BabyDetails> extends Man<T> {
    public T getDetails(){...}
}
```

But as [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711332/java-generics-of-generics/25711392#comment40191339_25711332) what you did is already fine

```
public class Baby extends Man {
    public BabyDetails getDetails(){...}
}
```

because overriding method can declare new return type as long as this type is subtype of return type declared in overridden method, for instance

```
List<String> method()
```

can be overridden by

```
ArrayList<String> method();
```

Comment: But how do you return ManDetails from Man class? You cannot do that in this solution.

Comment: @shayy What do you mean? In `Man` class `<T extends ManDetails>` so it represents also `ManDetails`. `class Man implements Human<ManDetails> {
    public ManDetails getDetails(){return new ManDetails();}
}` compiles fine for me.

Comment: A problem here: what should `Man`'s implementation return? I feel you're setting yourself up for `ClassCastException`. The `T extends Details` should probably be defined at a higher level in the hierarchy and `Man` should provide `ManDetails` as an argument.

Comment: Also this may work now because you can declare a new return type as you mentioned, but if i'll add more methods of which the generic (ManDetails/BabyDetails) is passed in the ctor or as a method param it will not work.

Comment: @shayy Can you post some code example which presents what could go wrong with this solution? I am not saying that my answer is correct, I am just mare student which wants to work with Java in the future so I am still learning. Anyway I don't see what could go wrong with this approach, if you will create instance of `Man` class with `Man<ManDetails> man = new Man<>();` you will only be able to pass instance of `ManDetails` to its `setDetails(T t){...}` method. This means you will also be able to pass `BabyDetails` because it is subtype of `ManDetails` but this is OK (with or without generics).

Comment: For example if you add a method like `public Iterable<ManDetails> getDetailsList()`. For Man it should return `Iterable<ManDetails>` but for Baby it should return `Iterable<BabyDetails>`

Comment: So what stops you from doing it? You are able to create `public Iterable<ManDetails> getDetailsList()` in `Man`. You even can declare it as `public Iterable<T> getDetailsList()` and use it in `Baby` class and it will be treated as `public Iterable<BabyDetails> getDetailsList()` if you will invoke it from reference of type `Baby<BabyDetails>`.

Comment: @shayy Please consider posting link to short but complete code example which will present problem with this approach because for now I am not able to see what you mean.